# Powershell Comparison works with hard coded date but not with calculated date

Tags: powershell

If I use this code, I get ALL quarantined devices returned regardless of the entry in WhenChanged

```
$DateTime = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)
$DateTimeStr = $DateTime.Tostring('MM/dd/yyyy')
$devices = get-mobiledevice -filter { deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined' -and WhenChanged -gt $DateTimeStr }
```

[Returned items (variable value in VSCode) using $DateTimeStr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUC3m.jpg)

If I manually enter the date as a string I get only the devices where the WhenChaged date is after the supplied date

```
$devices = get-mobiledevice -filter {deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined' -and WhenChanged -gt "01/07/2021"}
```

[Returned Items (Variable Value in VSCode) using hard coded date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJcPe.jpg)

---

Comment: `WhenChanged -gt $"01/07/2021` <-- this is not syntactically valid PowerShell, please update your post with the actual code

Comment: If whenchanged is a datetime this should work:  `WhenChanged -gt "01/07/2021"` or `whenchanged -gt $DateTime`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen apologies, I've corrected my typos

Comment: @js2010 I agree that it should work, but it doesn't. I can't see any reason at all why the two examples would bring back different results, but Ive posted images from VSCode that indicate they do and I get a much larger count using the calculated date string than I do using the hard-coded date string. Hence my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this myself, so it is unclear what the data type of `WhenChanged` really is..

1. If `WhenChanged` is a [Generalized-Time string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/adschema/s-string-generalized-time) with format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0Z or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.0[+/-]HHMM

```
    $refDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date
    $devices = Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'" | Where-Object {
        [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.WhenChanged, "yyyyMMddHHmmss.0K", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) -gt $refDate
    }
```

2. If `WhenChanged` is a [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) object

```
$refDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date
$devices = Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'" | 
           Where-Object { $_.WhenChanged -gt $refDate }
```

3. If `WhenChanged` is a string as shown in your images with format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

```
    $refDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).Date
    $devices = Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'" | Where-Object {
        [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.WhenChanged, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) -gt $refDate
    }
```

If in doubt, run

```
@(Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'")[0].WhenChanged.GetType()
```

to figure out what the actual data type is you are comparing against.

---

On closer look on the Parameters for [Get-MobileDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mobiledevice?view=exchange-ps#parameters), It seems you cannot use `-Filter` to test the `WhenChanged` property as -Filter can only be used on properties:

- ClientType
- DeviceAccessControlRule
- DeviceAccessState
- DeviceAccessStateReason
- DeviceActiveSyncVersion
- DeviceId
- DeviceImei
- DeviceMobileOperator
- DeviceModel
- DeviceOS
- DeviceOSLanguage
- DeviceTelephoneNumber
- DeviceType
- DeviceUserAgent
- FirstSyncTime
- FriendlyName
- ProvisioningFlags
- UserDisplayName

We therefore need a `Where-Object` clause to also test for the `WhenChanged` attribute.

Alternative No. 2 has been updated to reflect that

Comment: I get this error when I try that suggestion. `Where-Object : Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognised as a valid DateTime."` - I'm not familiar with ParseExact, can you provide any further help?

Comment: @sailingbikeruk Can you show us what `@(Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'")[0].WhenChanged.GetType()` returns?

Comment: I have added as an answer so you can see the table returned

Comment: @sailingbikeruk Aha, it apparently already is a DateTime object so in that case alternative `2` should work for you. When comparing, it is always best to compare DateTime objects because strings can be ambiguous (`01-02-2021` can be either `Jan 2, 2021` or `Feb 1, 2021`, depending on your current culture settings)

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Theo this is what happens. If I use alternative 2 exactly as per your suggestion I get the error `Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "The value "01" could not be converted to type System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime].` If I enclose the filter with braces `{}` instead of apostrophes `""` The code runs but returns all quarantined devices irrespective of the whenchanged date i.e. the same number of items as running the query without the date in the filter at all.

Comment: @sailingbikeruk I just had a closer look at what `-Filter` can do with cmdlet `Get-MobileDevice` and because of that I have updated the No. 2 code. Please could you try the edited code?

Comment: Thank you, that has been incredibly helpful and a great learning experience for me in the  vagaries of PowerShell filters and comparisons. I am not quite sue why it worked with the hard-coded string in the filter but option 2 is doing what I need to I have marked that as the answer. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

`@(Get-MobileDevice -Filter "deviceaccessstate -eq 'quarantined'")[0].WhenChanged.GetType()`

| IsPublic | IsSerial | Name | BaseType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | DateTime | System.ValueType |